# Cannot read sql statement into mysqlbinlog

Tags: mysql, backup, restore, delete, mysqlbinlog

Mysql 5.7 on Windows:

```
show global variables like 'binlog_format';
```

using me the `STATEMENT`

```
show master status;
```

gives me `log-bin.000053`

Now I execute this:

```
DELETE FROM test.emp WHERE EMPNO=109;
```

Now I want to read the contents of my mysqlbinlog:

```
mysqlbinlog log-bin.000053 > c:\backup\log.txt
```

An excerpt of the log file is this:

```
# at 1438
#170227  0:18:47 server id 1  end_log_pos 1514 CRC32 0x63bd770e     Query   thread_id=7 exec_time=0 error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1488151127/*!*/;
BEGIN
/*!*/;
# at 1514
#170227  0:18:47 server id 1  end_log_pos 1576 CRC32 0xf178e099     Table_map: `corsosql`.`emp` mapped to number 296
# at 1576
#170227  0:18:47 server id 1  end_log_pos 1644 CRC32 0x3efad847     Delete_rows: table id 296 flags: STMT_END_F

BINLOG '
V2KzWBMBAAAAPgAAACgGAAAAACgBAAAAAAEACGNvcnNvc3FsAANlbXAABwMPDwMK9gMGPAAeAAgC
f5ngePE=
V2KzWCABAAAARAAAAGwGAAAAACgBAAAAAAEAAgAH/4BxAAAABEx1aXMHQUNDT1VOVGwAAACHnw+A
GvQACgAAAEfY+j4=
'/*!*/;
# at 1644
#170227  0:18:47 server id 1  end_log_pos 1675 CRC32 0xfe9e00e6     Xid = 322
COMMIT/*!*/;
SET @@SESSION.GTID_NEXT= 'AUTOMATIC' /* added by mysqlbinlog */ /*!*/;
DELIMITER ;
# End of log file
/*!50003 SET COMPLETION_TYPE=@OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE*/;
/*!50530 SET @@SESSION.PSEUDO_SLAVE_MODE=0*/;
```

Where is my delete?

Why can I not see it?

How can I see the delete that I've just made in this file?

In all docs that I've read the command is the same, but when I tried to do it, I cannot see the delete.

Thank you.

---

### ** EDIT: **

I created a new myisam test table and inserted/deleted some rows.

After that, now magically the statements is readable in the log.

Why??

Mysql now shows all the statements that i make in both innodb and myisam tables.

I wasted 3 hours trying to read sql statements from the log, and from the moment i created a new myisam table, mysql starts showing me the statements.

Strange.

Seems like the table creation has awakened mysql starting to show the statements.

Someone can explain me why?

Comment: It could me that the delete never fully processed and was executing (or idle...) for a significant portion of time before the statement committed. The statement would not appear in the binlog unless it was committed.

Comment: Try 

`DELETE FROM test.emp WHERE EMPNO=109;COMMIT;`

And then mysqlbinlog...

Maybe your my.cnf innodb configuration is not writing on disk and everything remain only in ib_logfilex